# Convert complex strings to real numbers

Tags: python, numpy

After doing some calculation, I ended up with a data frame full of such values `'(312+0j)'`. Complex numbers but strings. How can I convert them back to real numbers? I have no complex numbers at all, due to some calculations in `np.eignval` it add the `+0j`. I am thinking of doing a regex but wanted to know if there is a faster and easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to complex:

```
complex('(312+0j)').real
# 312.0
```